# Suspect of keylogger/screen logger in Ubuntu machine

Tags: security, malware, rootkit

Seems my Ubuntu was hacked by a site while browsing. Is there a way that I can remove any logging software that may have been installed, or identify if a threat is present?

Comment: Why do you think you've been hacked? Do you know the name of the malware, etc.?

Comment: For economical reasons on the side of the attackers, there is almost no malware in the wild that can attack Linux systems through a web browsers successfully, so it's very unlikely that this happened to you even if you have an ancient browser version with an outdated, vulnerable Flash player. What leads you to believe that this happened to you nonetheless? Did you manually download and execute software from untrustworthy sources?

Answer (score 2):

### Using RKHUNTER for rootkit and malware checking

After a hacker attack, we should search for *rootkits* and *malwares* in our machine. These malicious software can corrupt files and compromise our control over the machine.

There are some softwares to help us searching for these malicious softwares, and one of them is **[RKHUNTER](http://rkhunter.sourceforge.net/)**.

#### Whats is rootkit?

From Wikipedia:

> A rootkit is a collection of computer software, typically malicious,
>   designed to enable access to a computer or areas of its software that
>   would not otherwise be allowed (for example, to an unauthorized user)
>   while at the same time masking its existence or the existence of other
>   software. The term rootkit is a concatenation of "root" (the
>   traditional name of the privileged account on Unix-like operating
>   systems) and the word "kit" (which refers to the software components
>   that implement the tool). The term "rootkit" has negative connotations
>   through its association with malware.
>
> Rootkit installation can be automated, or an attacker can install it
>   once they've obtained root or Administrator access. Obtaining this
>   access is a result of direct attack on a system (i.e.), exploiting a
>   known vulnerability (such as privilege escalation) or a password
>   (obtained by cracking or social engineering). Once installed, it
>   becomes possible to hide the intrusion as well as to maintain
>   privileged access. The key is the root or administrator access. Full
>   control over a system means that existing software can be modified,
>   including software that might otherwise be used to detect or
>   circumvent it.
>
> Rootkit detection is difficult because a rootkit may be able to
>   subvert the software that is intended to find it. Detection methods
>   include using an alternative and trusted operating system,
>   behavioral-based methods, signature scanning, difference scanning, and
>   memory dump analysis. Removal can be complicated or practically
>   impossible, especially in cases where the rootkit resides in the
>   kernel; reinstallation of the operating system may be the only
>   available solution to the problem. When dealing with firmware
>   rootkits, removal may require hardware replacement, or specialized
>   equipment.

#### Whats is malware?

From Wikipedia:

> Malware, short for malicious software, is a kind of software that can
>   be installed on a computer without approval from the computer's owner.
>   There are different kinds of malware that can hurt computers, such as
>   viruses and spyware. These programs can steal passwords, delete files,
>   collect personal information, or even stop a computer from working at
>   all. Computer security or anti-malware software is usually good at
>   stopping malware from installing itself. When security software is not
>   installed, malware can get into the computer. Getting rid of malware
>   can be difficult, even when using programs designed to remove it.

### Installing RKHUNTER

1. Open a terminal: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
2. Execute this command:
   `sudo apt-get install rkhunter`

You can left *postfix* unconfigured if installation asks for its configuration. *Postfix* is only used to send e-mail alerts, and can be configured later, when you want to use this feature.

### Scanning your system

1. Update rkhunter database. Execute:

   `rkhunter --update`

   `sudo rkhunter --propupd`
2. Check your system with:

   `sudo rkhunter -c`
3. *RKHUNTER* output is colorful and easy to understand. The software checks for several items in the system and every time an item is *OK* or a malware is *not found*, these messages are shown in green text. If something needs your attention, the text "*Warning*" is shown in red. If you want to see just the *WARNINGS*, use the command `sudo rkhunter -c --rwo`.
4. If you want to take a look at the log, execute:

   `cat /var/log/rkhunter.log`

### More information at:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rkhunter

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rkhunter-to-guard-against-rootkits-on-an-ubuntu-vps

http://www.tecmint.com/install-rootkit-hunter-scan-for-rootkits-backdoors-in-linux/